# WHERE DateInterval could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, format

In my database I've got **day** as int. Than I've got **$diff** which is DateTime.

```
$diff->format("%d"); 

SELECT * FROM smt WHERE day = $diff
```

And even when I use format before, it still gives me this:

> *Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in ...*

Thank you for your answers I hope I'm not missing something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$diff` is a [`DateInterval`](https://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object and thus cannot be interpolated or concatenated as a string as there is no string representation of it. I believe you are trying to interpolate the result from the [`format()`](https://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) method of DateInterval.

Try:

```
"SELECT * FROM smt WHERE day = " . $diff->format('d');
```

This query here should be safe from SQL injection providing that `$diff` is always a DateInterval object, however you should be using parameterized queries with MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved my mood. Will mark as answer :)